# Keystonejs: custom names to defaultColumns of Admin UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I use [keystonejs](http://keystonejs.com) as **Node.js CMS**

Model look like this:

```
Message.add({
  uId: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
  user: {
    name: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', initial: true, required: true },
    email: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', initial: true, required: true }
  },
  status: {
    display_name: { type: String, initial: false, required: true },
    state: { type: String, initial: false, required: true }
  }
})

Message.defaultColumns = 'user.name, title, status.display_name'
Message.register();
```

Titles of the columns in the generated **Admin UI** looks like this:

- User Name,
- Title
- Status Display_name

Is it possible to set custom names to `defaultColumns` to make it look better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `label` property to your [field options](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-options). The `label` is used as label for the field and as column name.

For example:

`display_name: { type: String, initial: false, required: true, label: 'Whatever you like' }`